# How to create a new array with keys based on calculated values of another array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$post` of the following format

```
$post[0] = [
    'id'    => '103',
    'date'  => '2016-04-17 16:30:12',
    'desc'  => 'content description'
];

$post[1] = [
    'id'    => '102',
    'date'  => '2016-04-17 12:30:12',
    'desc'  => 'content description'
];

$post[2] = [
    'id'    => '101',
    'date'  => '2016-04-17 10:30:12',
    'desc'  => 'content description'
];

$post[3] = [
    'id'    => '100',
    'date'  => '2016-04-16 08:30:12',
    'desc'  => 'content description'
];
```

I would like to use `strtotime(date)` from the `$post` as an unique array key, and create:

```
$summary['day-of-2016-04-17'] = [
    'counts' => '3'
];

$summary['day-of-2016-04-16'] = [
    'counts' => '1' 
];
```

Where `counts` is the number of occurrence of the date used as the key.

I only need to keep the date itself as the unique key and time value is irrelevant.

I'll need the key value to be unix timestamp for further processing.

How can I implement this in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `date` as key. The simplest way would be just use explode the date time, get the first fragment (which is the date),  and assign it just like any normal array:

```
$summary = [];
foreach($post as $value) {
    $dt = explode(' ', $value['date']); // break the date
    $day_of = "day-of-{$dt[0]}"; // create the naming key
    if(!isset($summary[$day_of])) { // initialize
        $summary[$day_of]['counts'] = 0;
    }
    $summary[$day_of]['counts']++; // increment
}
```